# Is there a word to describe the group of words which exist only to add politeness to an expression? (please, thanks, kindly)

Tags: single-word-requests, politeness

I'd like to refer to the whole group of "polite words" but calling them "polite words" doesn't sound accurate, I tried searching for an accurate term but could not find one.

The sentence I am trying to construct is:

> *Polite words* such as 'please' and 'thank you' are used to demonstrate the speakers willingness to comply with social norms and imply politeness when used in utterances

Comment: _phatic expressions_ comes to mind. Not sure if that applies to some of the above words.

Comment: As children, many of us were admonished to *mind/watch our **Ps and Qs***. Interestingly, there's uncertainty about what exactly those letters stand for, but I'm up for ***Please's*** and ***Thank you's***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers .   
from the phrase mind one's p's and q's, alluding to the difficulty a child learning to write has in distinguishing between p and q. (M-W)

Comment: @user405662 Thank you for the comment, "phatic expressions" is great! I read the wikipedia page on it and still wasn't able to find any more specific words for what I'm looking for. If there's anything more specific that would be even better, but if nobody else offers something then I'd accept that as the answer if you posted it.

Comment: @Gio: The *full* (subscription-only) OED acknowledges the existence of that possible etymology, but *inter alia* they say of it: *However, the chronology of the senses would argue against this, and no such connotation is evident in the earliest quotations.* They also say *Another suggestion is that the expression refers to a sailor's pea-coat and queue (tarred pig-tail)*. But ty for making me investigate further to find *The expression is **unlikely to be a shortening of pleases and thank yous**, since this is apparently not attested independently as a phrase before the 20th cent.*

Comment: I just call them 'politeness markers'.

Comment: For the record, bars always want you to mind your tab of Pints and Quarts. Apologies for the mini-splaining. Though Pls and Thank yous is original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offer "*phatic expression*", with the caveat that it may or may not cover all the words listed in the OP's question. But many such *filler* words do come under the rubric of phatic expression.

> *Phatic communication* is popularly known as small talk: the nonreferential use of language to share feelings or establish a mood of sociability rather than to communicate information or ideas. The ritualized formulas of phatic communication (such as "Uh-huh" and "Have a nice day") are generally intended to attract the attention of the listener or prolong communication. Also known as phatic speech, phatic communion, phatic language, social tokens, and chit-chat.

> "[P]hatic utterances constitute a mode of action just in their being voiced. In short, a phatic utterance communicates not ideas but attitude, the speaker's presence, and the speaker's intention of being sociable."
> (*Brooks Landon, Building Great Sentences: How to Write the Kinds of Sentences You Love to Read. Plume, 2013*)

[ThoughtCo.]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "civil minded words", "genteel" or "affable" or "amicable" words. Or "geniality inducing words"